# Error 413 in websocket, how to handle?

Tags: php, websocket, zeromq

I have been developing a websocket server until recently I have encountered a 413 Entity too large error. I am using ratchetphp on my server. Have anyone encountered this? Is there anything I can do so that this won't occur? If there isn't anything I can do please help me recreate this error, the current solution I have on fixing this is clearing my browser's cache. I only find this error out by checking network tab on developer tools using chrome, but if clients connect to the server without knowledge of developer tools how can I let them know that they need to clear their cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of reading codes inside ratchetphp library I have found out that http connection upgrade header is limited to 4kb of data. So all I did to solve this is to increase the limit.

If you also encounter this error, see file

> Ratchet/Http/HttpRequestParser.php

Hope this helps

Comment: it helped thanks.  
            ` if (strlen($context->httpBuffer) > (int)$this->maxSize) {
                      //    throw new \OverflowException("Maximum buffer size of {$this-
                        >maxSize} exceeded parsing HTTP header");
               }`

Comment: How did you increase the limit? Did you just change public $maxSize = 4096; ?
The documentation says 4096 can prevent attacks

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with same problem and the solution was rather trivial : *Deleting cookies in my browser* (Google Chrome).

Comment: That was also my solution before, but if you try the solution above it won't occur anymore